# Sonarqube sonar.analysis.mode preview mode gets ignored

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I have a sonarqube plugin that acts as a `PostJob`, that shall retrieve information about resolved/new issues.

Therefore I try to run my analysis in preview mode, but when I run `mvn compile package sonar:sonar -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview` the mode is `issues` (I use sonarqube 6.2).

When I change it to `mvn compile package sonar:sonar -Dsonar.analysis.mode=issues`, it is logically the same output and when I change it to `mvn compile package sonar:sonar -Dsonar.analysis.mode=publish`, the results get (as expected) published.

For my only `preview` seems not to be recognised.

Any idea why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try adding Issues report plugin in Project Configuration-->Settings-->Issues Report

Comment: not sure how this should help ? The plugin is deprecated and seems not to let my plugin recognise the flag `preview` ?!